# How to configure IAM authorizer for HTTP ApiGateway in AWS SAM?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

We have a service build with AWS SAM. Now we want to add authentication to it. We have one HTTP ApiGateway and we want to add an IAM authenticator to it. Unfortunately, I can't find any example or documentation on how to do that? I've tried, following options:

```
  exampleApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      CorsConfiguration: True
      DefinitionBody:
        'Fn::Transform':
          Name: 'AWS::Include'
          Parameters:
            Location: 'openapi.yaml'
      StageName: v2
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
```

and

```
  exampleApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      CorsConfiguration: True
      DefinitionBody:
        'Fn::Transform':
          Name: 'AWS::Include'
          Parameters:
            Location: 'openapi.yaml'
      StageName: v2

  fnExample:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.example
      Role: !GetAtt dataLambdaRole.Arn
      Events:
        getExample:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            Path: /example
            Method: get
            ApiId: !Ref exampleApi
            Auth:
              Authorizer: AWS_IAM
```

unfortunately, both of them finish with error. Can I ask you to share an example or instruction on how to  configure the IAM authorizer for HTTP ApiGateway in AWS SAM template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it.
Unfortunately, it looks that currently (21 January 2021) it is impossible to confiure IAM security for HTTP API using SAM template. This is what I found in AWS documentation:

| Mechanisms for controlling access | AWS::Serverless::HttpApi | AWS::Serverless::Api |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lambda authorizers | ✓ | ✓ |
| IAM permissions |  | ✓ |
| Amazon Cognito user pools | ✓ | ✓ |
| API keys |  | ✓ |
| Resource policies |  | ✓ |
| OAuth 2.0/JWT authorizers | ✓ |  |

More details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-controlling-access-to-apis.html)

There is some work on AWS side to fix that:

- https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/pull/1876
- https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/pull/1878

Comment: Just an update for anyone looking for the current status on the issue.  There's a PR open to fix this: https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/pull/1924